# Dialogue Editing Workflow

Tags: dialogue, sound-editing, re-recording

When dialogue editors are working on a feature length movie, how are the tracks laid out for the entire movie? imagine the movie has about 50 completely different scenes on different locations, and each scene has 2 people talking to each other all the time. If the dialogue is cut in 2 or more tracks for one scene, then the entire movie should have about 100 tracks or more, am I right??

whats the game plan here??

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, with any sort of sound post work on features, don't consider a feature length project to be one single timeline.

Best practise with long-form work is to split the project into "reels". This should be done in conjunction with the picture editor. Splitting the project into reels assists with undergoing re-conform operations as there is no such thing as picture lock. Ever.

Each reel will be about 20 minutes long and will start at an Hour boundary. For example, reel 1 starts at 01:00:00:00, reel 2 starts at 02:00:00:00, reel 3 starts at 03:00:00:00 etc for as many reels as you need.

Secondly, the dialogue editors job is to edit dialogue, not mix dialogue. There may be a need to perform some basic de-noising and treatment, but this should be done in conjunction with the re-recording mixer.

It is not a good idea to split every single scene into a different track as automation can be easily used in the mix to separate mix parameters in order to match dialogue.

Remember, as a dialogue editor, your job is to edit, not mix.

Comment: Yeah but, if you have two completely different scenes: i.e. one interior (a small quiet room) and one exterior (middle of the woods), the voices are gonna sound completely different. The voices and the tones will be worlds apart. How do "professional" dialogue editors edit two different locations on the same track?

Comment: It's not your job to worry about "how it sounds". It's your job to edit the dialogue. Just edit. Doesn't matter whether you put it on a separate track or not. You just need to edit the dialogue. You havn't got over the "I'm not a re-recording mixer" bit yet. Forget about the mix. Just Edit.